# How to Re-Establish Clicked Events?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

How do I re-establish the clicked event of a Xamarin Forms button?

The button was made invisible and it's footprint covered by a popup listview. The listview was subsequently removed, but the button does not respond. Other buttons on the page do.

This only happens on the iOS version of the page.

Comment: If it its invisible you can't click on it. after you remove the popup you should make the button visible.

Comment: Thanks. It was. I have also reset the clicked method and re-enable the button Still nothing.

Comment: Share the code please. GitHub for example.

Comment: I found that by moving the setting of the Clicked event handler from XAML to code just before making visible and enabling the button made the buttons responsive.